# Object gets modified in a thread function after returning from calling function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am using an open source Json library called Json11. I am taking a Json object and then passing it to a ThreadPool to do work on it. When I begin processing the Json object in the thread function it was get modified soon as the function that created the object returns.

```
void add_to_pool(std::string json_string) {
    std::string err;
    json11::Json json_object = json11::Json::parse(json_string.c_str(), e);

    for (auto it : json_object.object_items()) {
        for (auto ait : it.second.array_items()) {
            PTP_WORK work_item = CreateThreadpoolWork((PTP_WORK_CALLBACK)thread_func, &ait, &tp_env);
            SubmitThreadpoolWork(work_item);
```

`thread_func()`

```
void thread_func(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, json11::Json data, PTP_WORK work) {
    for (auto key: data.object_items()) {
        std::cout << key.first << ":" << key.second.string_value() << "\n";
```

The `add_to_pool()` will take a string version of my Json. It will `parse()` it into a object. The first `for` loop will go through the first layer of items, which right now it only has one. Then second `for` loop will go through the next layer which also has one thing and it is an array of objects.

```
{
    "first_layer": {
        "second_layer": [
            {
                "key":"value,
                "yes":"no"
            },
            {
                "example":"here"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue I get is if `add_to_pool()` returns before the `thread_func()` can process everything then `data` turns into a invalid pointer and the program crashes. I have tried to create a new object and point it to the old one but the new object just points to the same pointers as the original.

I am not sure if anything exists in C++ to do this or if I have to make a function that will manually loop through all items and make a copy?

Comment: You are concurrently modifying a data structure, which is a race condition, which is undefined behaviour. If you want to work on separate copies, you need to deep copy the object (don't create another pointer, create another object and copy assign it). If you want to have one thread wait for the other to be done, have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore.

Comment: Each iteration of the inner loop creates a new `ait` object that gets destroyed at the end of each iteration. Unless the thread function runs and uses the pointer before the end of the iteration, which is unlikely, undefined behavior occurs, [and demons will fly out of everyone's noses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).